# Apache subdomain will not resolve

Tags: apache, apache2, subdomain

I have apache2 running on Ubuntu and have been hosting this site, `domain.com`, successfully. Now, I'm trying to add a subdomain for a project tracker called phabricator and I can't get it to work.

Below are my configurations in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`. The header is the file name

**default**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin support@domain.com
        ServerName domain.com
        ServerAlias www.domain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/public_html
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/domain.com/public_html>
                Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

**phabricator.domain.com**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin support@domain.com
        ServerName phabricator.domain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/public_html/phabricator/webroot

        <Directory /var/www/domain.com/public_html/phabricator/webroot>
                Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule ^/rsrc/(.*)     -                       [L,QSA]
        RewriteRule ^/favicon.ico   -                       [L,QSA]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$          /index.php?__path__=$1  [B,L,QSA]

</VirtualHost>
```

I ran `a2ensite phabricator.domain.com` and then `service apache2 restart`. But when I got to `phabricator.domain.com`, nothing is resolved. Not even a server error. I confirmed phabricator is working by point **default** to it, so I know its a subdomain issue.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was outside of Apache entirely. I neglected to add a CNAME record to my DNS configuration.

To fix the issue, I added the CNAME record phabricator to point to `domain.com`